# slicknav not working on iphone 6 safari

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari, slicknav

I have slicknav working on a desktop in chrome, ie, safari and firefox.  When I run on the iphone 6 it works in chrome but not in safari.  my js function looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
});
```

the safari console from iphone 6 says:

```
$("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
```

is not a function.  Have no idea how to fix this.  help appreciated.

here's a link to the website:

[halloween](http://www.cs401.netai.net/Halloween3/halloween.html)

if you reduce the screen size you'll see the slicknav plugin working on a desktop.  But unless you use chrome it doesn't work on the iphone 6

Did some more testing and the plugin works fine on the iphone 6S but still not working on the Iphone 6

Answer (score 0):

If I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
 });
```

It doesn’t work on the iphone 6 but it does seem to work everywhere else

However, if I use

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $("#nav_lat").slicknav({prependTo:"#mobile_menu"});
 });
```

It seems to work every where
Could someone explain what's going on?